# overlapping objects - help

Tags: actionscript-3

can someone help me with the following problem please:

In my game there appear scores when you shoot down enemies. That kinda works so far but they overlap when the enemies were too close to each other when shot down.
Now what I'd like to do is to prevent the overlapping of the scores. The basic idea I had was to loop through the array of scores and to check the distance to each other.
Problem is that it doesn't work. Can someone help please?

```
private function checkScoreDistance():void
{
scoreManager.scoreCount = scoreManager.scores.length;
if (scoreManager.scoreCount >= 1)
{
    scoreManager.scoreCount = scoreManager.scores.length - 1;
    scoreManager.scoreCountTwo = scoreManager.scores.length - 2;

    scoreOne: for (var scoreCtr:int = scoreManager.scoreCount; scoreCtr >= 0; scoreCtr--)
    {

        tempScore = scoreManager.scores[scoreCtr];
        tempScore.point.x = tempScore.x;
        tempScore.point.y = tempScore.y;
        oldtempScoreX = tempScore.x;
        oldtempScoreY = tempScore.y;

        var tempScoreTwo:Score;
        scoreTwo: for (var scoreCtrTwo:int = scoreManager.scoreCountTwo; scoreCtrTwo >= 0; scoreCtrTwo--)
        {
            tempScoreTwo = scoreManager.scores[scoreCtrTwo];
            tempScoreTwo.point.x = tempScoreTwo.x;
            tempScoreTwo.point.y = tempScoreTwo.y;

            oldtempScoreTwoX = tempScoreTwo.x;
            oldtempScoreTwoY = tempScoreTwo.y; 

            var scoresX:Number; 
            scoresX = oldtempScoreTwoX - oldtempScoreX;

            var scoresY:Number;
            scoresY = oldtempScoreTwoY - oldtempScoreY;

            var dist:Number;

            dist = Math.sqrt(scoresX * scoresX + scoresY * scoresY);

            if (dist <= 25)
            {
                oldtempScoreX -= 25;
                oldtempScoreTwoX += 25;

                oldtempScoreY -= 25;
                oldtempScoreTwoY += 25;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, you seem to be lacking some code to *do* something with the values you compute in `oldtempScoreX` and `oldtemScoreTwoX`. Apparently there is nothing to actually move anything based on the calculations ...

Also, what if an object is bumped left because it has a close neighbor to the right and then afterwards is bumped right because it now has a close neighbor to the left?

Also also: You seem to be blindly bumping `oldtempScore` to the northwest and `oldtempScoreTwo` to the southeast, without actually checking that their relative position is such that this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it again and let you know when it's working.:)